# glment error with cv.glmnet()

Tags: r, glmnet

when I analyse my data with this code(glment Rpackage), met this error:

> lasso_fit <- cv.glmnet(x, y, family='cox', type.measure = 'deviance')
>   Error in response.coxnet(y) : 
>     negative event times encountered;  not permitted for Cox family

this is my code

```
x <- as.matrix(survival_cancer[,gsub(resSigAll@rownames, pattern = '-', replacement = '_')])
y <- survival_cancer[,c('overall_survival', 'censoring_status')]
names(y) <- c('time', 'status')
y$time <- as.double(y$time)
y$status <- as.double(y$status)
y <- as.matrix(survival::Surv(y$time, y$status))
lasso_fit <- cv.glmnet(x, y, family='cox', type.measure = 'deviance')
```

the data type of x

```
         gene1 gene2 gene3 gene4 gene5 gene6 gene7 gene8 gene9 gene10 gene11 
sample1
sample2
sample3
sample4
sample5
sample6
sample7
sample
sample
```

the type of y:

```
 time  status
 100      0
  90      1
```

I don't konw where is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The error message is referenced from line#5 of coxnet function written at https://github.com/jeffwong/glmnet/blob/master/R/coxnet.R.

Kindly check if the summation of your time outcome variable is less than 0 or if the vector itself has entries = 0.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Answers that are barely more than a link to an external site are discouraged as the link may be short lived. Consider moving to comments or flesh out the answer with code. Check out the guidance for answering questions [answer].